# win32 app toolbar icon are not loading on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: winapi, mfc, win32gui

I have a win32 MFC application where in for this app for one dialog i am loading a toolbar and placing icons on top of toolbar. Very first time when i open this dialog icons are shown properly but after closing this dialog and reopening it again either no icon comes or some different icons comes but expected icons are not coming. this issue is only happening on Windows 7 x64 ultimate.

On windows xp every thing runs smoothly.

please suggest what could be the cause.

One intresting thing is if I right click on my app/exe and set compatibility mode windows xp sp3 then everything works perfectly but application performance decresed(e.g launching app, switch moduled inside application etc.)

we did a test on Windows 7 x32 and it was working perfectly.
Even it is working with many Windows 7 x64 bit machine(for example my desktop which is also Windows 7 x64 Enterprise edition).

We have observed this issue in one of our test machine which is a Windows 7 x64 Ultimate edition.

One more intresting thing I observed yesterday,

1. log-in to Windows 7 x64 Ultimate machine physicially.
2. launch the exe and then launch the dialog where icons are missing on the toolbar.
3. now without closing the exe and dialog lock the screen.
4. Do a remote desktop from other machine to earlier used Windows 7 x64 Ultimate where exe and dialog running.
5. we observed that when we do remote desktop Icons are visible properly.
6. Now close the remote desktop connection without closing the exe and dialog.
7. Come back to the same earlier used Windows 7 x64 and unloack it physically.
8. We observed that now Icons are visible properly.

Any suggestion why is it so?